# Detecting when a user scrolls to a certain position/element on a page

Tags: javascript, css

I've seen a cool little effect on some websites where the top header/navigation menu is fixed, and shrunk as the user scrolls past a certain point on a webpage.

How can I detect when a user scrolls to a certain position of a page?

Comment: Please show what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var topShow = 150;

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > topShow) {
        // your logic here
    }
});
```